# JavaFX: On button click, how to execute line of code, then thread.sleep x seconds, then run remaining code

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

On JavaFX, after a button click I want to run some lines of code, wait x seconds, then finish the remaining code. This is what I have tried.

```
        /* On button click */
    buttonD.setOnAction(action -> {

        /* Gets text from text field */
        String text = input.getText();

        /* Some alteration to the text from another class */
        CaesarCipher obj = new CaesarCipher();
        String varD = obj.decrypt(text, 10);

        /* Changes what was in the text field, to the altered text */
        input.setText(varD + "\n");

        /* Wait 10 seconds */
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* After 10 seconds, clear the text field*/
        input.clear();

    });
```

The problem is once I click my button, it automatically starts counting down the timer, then goes down to clear the textfield, instead of first changing the text inside the textfield and then waiting x seconds and finally clearing the textfield.

Comment: that's wrong - even from the thought model: you don't "wait" for anything. Technically, you __must not__ sleep the fx application thread. Instead use a background thread doing the timing and signaling back into the ui when stuff should happen. In fx there's extensive support, see f.i. Timeline, Animation, Task. There are tons of examples here on SO on how to do it - when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what goes wrong :)

Comment: @kleopatra thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I got it working by using Timeline.